# how send template from external system (Servicenow) to Docusign

Tags: docusignapi, servicenow, servicenow-rest-api

I am currently working Servicenow to Docusign integration where a user raises request from Servicenow and i want to send a template to the requested user. I created my demo docusign instance & template, please help me with the api to trigger an template and send it to the user using integration.

I tried to use below api's to get the template id but i keep reading the documentation but no where i found something to send a template from external system

[https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/accounts/${account_id}/templates](https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/accounts/$%7Baccount_id%7D/templates)

This gives me the template id

Comment: WELCOME to StackOverflow! Please check (accept) the best answer to each of your questions. THANK YOU

Answer (score 1):

Start with the [QuickStart](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/quickstart) in your favorite language. Use workflow 2, Sending a signing request via email.

You'll want to use the JWT grant to obtain an access token for DocuSign since your application will be sending signing requests (envelopes) autonomously.

Ask additional StackOverflow questions when you run into a problem or question.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I did configured OAuth and i am able to get the user info and templates which i did with Authorization Code. So for trigger a template via api i have to go with JWT ?

Comment: Can anyone please help with the end point api to be used to send trigger a template and sent to the recipient